# Where are we supposed to go to when we need some help?

Tags: communication

In a big company, we are for example 10 employees simple IT developers and only one IT manager. If I'm new in the company, and no one goes to me to help me to explain me things to do my work... May I go to the IT manager first or to one of my colleagues simple developers first ?

Answer (score 10):

## Ask your team lead or manager who you should talk to.

If you're new to the office, odds are that they're going to expect you to have questions. Ask your boss who you should ask them to; they'd be able to inform you who you should direct those work-related questions to; this might be them, but is likely going to be one of your more experienced coworkers. Once you've done so, address any further such questions to said person, unless they're directly related to things that you'd need to speak to the manager about.